# variable not printing to screen - angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a small controller and some basic data. Here is my code. I am not sure why when I click the link, my messages won't show. In the console, I get no errors at all. I consoled the variables, and they show up. For some reason, it doesn't work in the view. I am not sure what I am missing.

**index.html -- navigation menu**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href ng-click="showMessage('Home')">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="showMessage('Work')">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="showMessage('Contact')">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

<div class="container" ng-controller="menu">
 <h1> {{ message }} </h1>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('website', [])
.controller('menu', function($scope) {
    // show the message on click
    $scope.showMessage = function(messages) {
        $scope.message = messages;
        console.log($scope.message);
        return $scope.message;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define two times the ng-controller, both will have separated scope.

You need to put all usages of controller in a block:

```
<div ng-controller="menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href ng-click="showMessage('Home')">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="showMessage('Work')">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="showMessage('Contact')">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container">
        <h1> {{ message }} </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes, and that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 separate instances of the `menu` controller and they do not share the same scope

When you update one of the scopes, the other has no knowledge of it. You can use a service to share data across controllers or change structure you are using implementing separate controller instances

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean.